# Odd/Even Non-Working Perfect Shuffle Algorithm Error

Tags: java, shuffle

```
private static final int SHUFFLE_COUNT = 5;


private static int[] VALUES = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};  


//broken for when  SHUFFLECOUNT and VALUES are EVEN
public static void perfectShuffle(int[] values) {
    int[] values1 = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    int k = 0; 
    for(int j = 0; j <= values.length / 2; j++) {
        values[k] = values1[j];
        k = k + 2; 
    }
    k = 1; 
    for(int j = (values.length / 2) + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
        values[k] = values1[j];
        k = k + 2; 
    }

}

public void testPerfectShuffle() {
    System.out.println("Results of " + SHUFFLE_COUNT +
                             " consecutive perfect shuffles:");
    for (int j = 1; j <= SHUFFLE_COUNT; j++) {
        perfectShuffle(VALUES);
        System.out.println("  " + j + ":" + Arrays.toString(VALUES));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I am working on implementing a perfect shuffle algorithm and for some reason, my test works when ever the number of values tested with is odd such as  `private static int[] VALUES = {1,2,3,4,5};`  *passes* although, sadly,  `private static int[] VALUES = {1,2,3,4,5,6}`  does not. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the loop condition to "next bigger" helped.  It does shuffle and it does it for even as well as for odd arrays. So it works.
Spot that with your code(independent of the size of the array:5,7.. the first number always stays in its place).
Output of your unmodified code with an odd sized array:

```
  1:[1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
  2:[1, 5, 4, 3, 2]
  3:[1, 3, 5, 2, 4]
  4:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  5:[1, 4, 2, 5, 3]
```

The below code behaves analog - as designing a completely different shuffle algorithm was not the question - was it?

If I got the logic wrong, please put some information about how exactly the shuffle should logically work in your question - otherwise I have no way of knowing except that it should shuffle all numbers with exception for the array boundaries(may stay), which the below code does.

(And I made the testMethod static so I could just call it from main - simplified testing for me).

```
public class PerfectShuffle {

    private static final int SHUFFLE_COUNT = 5;

    private static int[] VALUES = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

//broken for when  SHUFFLECOUNT and VALUES are EVEN
    public static void perfectShuffle(int[] values) {
        int[] values1 = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
        int k = 0;
        //take the next bigger int for length/2(round up) 
        for (int j = 0; j < (values.length -1) / 2 +1 ; j++) {
            values[k] = values1[j];
            k = k + 2;
        }
        k = 1;
        //take the next bigger int for length/2(round up)
        for (int j = (values.length -1)/ 2  + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
            values[k] = values1[j];
            k = k + 2;
        }

    }

    public static void testPerfectShuffle() {
        System.out.println("Results of " + SHUFFLE_COUNT
                + " consecutive perfect shuffles:");
        for (int j = 1; j <= SHUFFLE_COUNT; j++) {
            perfectShuffle(VALUES);
            System.out.println("  " + j + ":" + Arrays.toString(VALUES));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String ... args){
        testPerfectShuffle();
    }
}
```

Sample run:

```
Results of 5 consecutive perfect shuffles:
  1:[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
  2:[1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 6]
  3:[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
  4:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  5:[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

FWIW an in and an outshuffle. Both are only supposed to work correctly only with even array sizes(depending on the definition of "correct") but they don't throw errors with odd:

```
public static void inShuffle(int[] values) {
    int[] values1 = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length / 2; j++) {
        values[j*2] = values1[j];
    }
    for (int j = 1; j < values.length / 2; j++) {
        values[j*2-1] = values1[(values.length / 2)+j-1];
    }
}

public static void outShuffle(int[] values) {
    int[] values1 = Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length);
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length / 2; j++) {
        values[j*2] = values1[(values.length / 2)+j];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length / 2; j++) {
        values[j*2+1] = values1[j];
    }
}
```